# iOS - Realm for react-native ,unkonw execution context,

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

it show 'unkonw execution context' when I

```
import Realm from 'realm';
```

The same problem -> [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557984/unknown-execution-context-when-import-realm-in-react-native)

how to solve it in xcode and why .

Comment: how you have installed ? Which one ? https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation

Comment: @sehaswaranmayilerum he's not using Swift but React Native!

Comment: @OrangeEvan How did you install Realm ?

Comment: @Ludovic Do we use import Realm in  React Native!

Comment: @sehaswaranmayilerum No but import from like written in the question! Swift use import without 'from'. Plus, for Realm for Swift, toi import RealmSwift but not Realm.

Comment: @Ludovic  I use Objective-C and
install Realm by npm and react-native link.But the project is  linked by cocoapod with `pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native' ` as same as the official website show.

Comment: Wy are you using Pod to install React ? It's not the official install process : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html Maybe it's because you are using an existing objective-c app ?

Comment: @Ludovic  : Not the geeting-started but Integration with existing apps : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html. I am willing to turn it to react-native gradually from native app.

Comment: @OrageEvan Ok! I imagine you're opening the workspace file and not the xproj ?

Comment: @Ludovic Yes,I opened the workspace file but not the project.I find maybe I update a wrong   version of realm which need react-native 0.43.3.And I roll back to a  lower version.It is OK.So,I am going to update all the dependencies.By the way, to use fastlist .

Comment: @OrangeEvan Ok I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Ludovic Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you're using the installation/setup steps for React Native that can be found [here](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#installation). If you're still experiencing problems after following those steps (and I recommend trying again to see if it had to do with *that* project), try reinstalling React Native.

Let me know if you have any issues with this and I'll happily work with you to resolve the issue and edit my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks ! But I think ，probably， I don't have a good description of the problem. Actually the problem is not about the installation but `import Realm from 'realm';` or not .

Answer (score 0):

update the react-native over 0.43 if use the newest realm.
By the way, you should update your cocoapod over 1.2.0 best that version 1.1 will link project wrong.